# How to apply @guard before @validator in laravel lighthouse graphql?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am using lighthouse in laravel for graphql. using `@validator` I am writing validation for all the input data. and `@guard` directive to authenticate the route.

But the problem is, validations is being done before guarding the route. Which means, for validations like `exists, unique`, client can know the existed data without authentication.
So, need to guard and authenticated first then only the validation rules need to be applied. But Laravel lighthouse apply validation before guard. How to fix this?

Comment: show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Read [guard documentaion](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/directives.html#guard) "Note that @guard does not log in users. To ensure the user is logged in, add the AttemptAuthenticate middleware to your lighthouse.php middleware config." 
If it is not your case add more details what you want to do.

Comment: @mostafa yes i got it. I've used the AttemptAuthenticate middleware as in default it is being used. What I want is check authentication before doing validation.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I've tried this one https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1780#issuecomment-833832193
It does the job. but as the author says, it runs guard twice